# Can I use the Apple Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter?

Tags: hardware, usb, display, macbook, apple

If I get an Apple [Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB571Z/A), will Ubuntu be able to use it?

[image: Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it should work. Use one all the time on my MacBookPro6,2 for meetings both in OSX and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I think it shouldn't matter what OS you use. According to Wikipedia, an active adapter is needed for Dual-Link DVI, so the adapter does the necessary conversion by itself, without depending on the operating system or any drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with the above - Ubuntu is more interested in powering the graphics processor on your card than figuring out what's connected to it. It's up to the graphics card to decide that for most graphics cards anyway.